# disk2vhd.exe missing volumes?

Tags: windows-xp, sp3, disk2vhd

I was trying to create a [Virtual PC clone](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/convert-windows-xp-into-a-windows-7-virtual-machine-with-disk2vhd/3091) of my Toshiba laptop today, and I noticed that it's C: drive does not appear in the list of `Volumes to include:` (or any volumes at all for that matter! There are none listed.)

Is there some service I need to turn on that will list the volumes?

Comment: disk2vhd uses a snapshot to back up a drive. I've never run into this problem, but perhaps that will help.

Comment: Ok well, I turned on the Removable Storage Service...because the ntbackup required it.

But I guess I have to actually make a backup huh?  (It's my junker computer, so there's no backup for it, but I guess I'll make one anyway).

Comment: So nobody knows this one huh?

Answer (score 2):

I know this probably sounds dumb, but make sure the account you are logged in as is an Administrator account in windows (and also try running disk2vhd from a flashdrive in the administrator account) it didn't work for me until I did this.

Comment: this routine check, while good, is usually added as a comment before posting as an answer

Comment: @Lizz users need 50 rep before they can comment.

Comment: He could also make sure he's running the app as an administrator... (right click, run as administrator...)

Comment: Running as administrator by means of the right click menu didn't work for me (in Windows7). I had to login with an admin account for it to show the volumes. This answer actually motivated me to try this after I already tried "run as administrator".